# What to do if the data in my file contains the delimiter (ç) of the values

Tags: java

I need to import batches of files, analyze the data and produce a report.
There are 3 types of data within these files.
For each type of data there is a different layout.

**Seller details**
The salesperson data has the format id 001 and the line will have the following format:
001çCPFçNameçSalary

**Client's data**
The customer data has the format id 002 and the line will have the following format:
002çCNPJçNameçBusiness Area

**Sales data**
Sales data has the format id 003. Within the sales line, there is the list
of items, which is surrounded by square brackets []. The line will have the following format:
003çSale IDç [Item ID-Item Quantity-Item Price] çSalesman name

**Sample Data**
The following is an example of the data that the system should be able to read.
001ç1234567891234çPedroç50000
001ç3245678865434çPauloç40000.99
002ç2345675434544345çJose da SilvaçRural
002ç2345675433444345çEduardo PereiraçRural
003ç10ç [1-10-100,2-30-2.50,3-40-3.10] çPedro
003ç08ç [1-34-10,2-33-1.50,3-40-0.10] çPaulo

What to do when the field values ​​contain the delimiter (ç)?

Example:
001ç1234567891234çAssunçãoç50000

Comment: There is not much you can do. This is a problem with the file format. There should have been some escaping rules in place for the delimiter as part of the field value.

Comment: As a workaround (depends on the data if this really works) you could take just the first second and last delimiter if there are more than 3.

Comment: Educate the publisher of your data about the delimiters specifically designated by US-ASCII and Unicode: Unit separator (31), Record separator (30), Group separator (29), File separator (28). There is no need to hack your own delemiters. Another possibility is  [*CSV*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean about having to "do" something about it.

But there should be no problem processing data that uses `ç` as a delimiter.  Provided that `ç` is ONLY used as a delimiter.

- If you are using `String.split`, you can use `"ç"` as the separator regex.
- If you are using `Scanner`, you can include `"ç"` in the delimiters.
- A typical CSV reader library will; allow you to use `"ç"` as a field separator ... instead of `","`.

---

It is also possible that the `ç` actually represents something else, and you have a mismatch between the character set / encoding used to write the files and the one you are using to read it.

---

It is not a good idea to use `ç` as a delimiter.  While C+cedila is primarily used in non-English text (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%87), you do occasionally see it in English text.  If you use it as a delimiter, there is a possibility of a conflict ... which could be problematic if the file format doesn't have a syntax for quoting or escaping the delimiter.

Which leads to this:

> What to do when the field values ​​contain the delimiter (ç)?

Then:

- You need a quoting or escaping scheme in the file syntax.
- If you don't have one, then your file syntax is ambiguous.
- There is no *simple* way to parse the file if the syntax is ambiguous.  (You need a disambiguation heuristic that works in all practical examples.  You probably need a hand built parser to implement the heuristic.)
- If the ambiguity cannot be resolved via a heuristic, then you need to get the file syntax changed; e.g. add escaping / quoting support, or use a different delimiter.